# Delete a Ped from Process

Tags: anylogic

I have a Pedestrian agent which has two states: Healthy and Injured. I have connected  this statechart to the Ped flow chart. When Ped goes to the injured state, it needs to `deleteSelf()` and a new agent should be addded to the ped population. This population has one ped when its injured a new ped comes to the model.

However, I realized that I can not use `deleteSelf()` in the injured state while ped is in a block in the flowchart. Instead of that I used `cancel(this)` in the injured state; for all the blocks that ped might be there when injured. For example;

```
main.goToExcSite.cancel(this);
main.pedWait.cancel(this);
main.exitExcSite.cancel(this);
```

And I wrote `ped.deleteSelf();` in the on cancel sections of those blocks. Again. It is does not accept `deleteSelf();` while running the model.

How can I do this? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Hi Neda, always share the error msg (better screenshot) as well, helps a lot.

Comment: Also, what block is this? A ped-library flow block (where `ped` works) or a process library block (where you need to use `agent`)

Comment: Hi Benjamin, it is a ped-library flow block. And I added the error to the main question. Thanks.

Comment: As a first impression, it seems this can be solved by using the "remove" function. You need to first remove the agent from the flow chart block (e.g. pedWait.remove(agent) ), then have the agent delete itself. But I'll let Benjamin confirm that.

Comment: Thank you Emile. It works perfect now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`deleteSelf` is really a low-level internal function that you shouldn't typically need to explicitly call yourself. It just removes them from their population and has no 'synchronisation' with the process flow (i.e., it doesn't also remove them from the process flow); all process flows expect the agents therein to exist in a population throughout their process lifecycle, hence you get the error you mentioned if you try to remove them from their population whilst they're in a flow.

In general for process flows, you should delete agents in one via the standard mechanism for all process flows: flowing into a sink block. (And use exit blocks if you want them to leave the flow but remain in existence.)

In the Pedestrian library case, use the built-in cancel ports (as you were attempting) **and send them to a PedSink block from these ports**.

(If you had *other* possible reasons to cancel peds from blocks that's fine; you just have conditional logic in the cancel flow to do whatever is needed depending on why you had to cancel them, which might mean storing the cancellation reason in the ped agent...)

AnyLogic libraries *also* allow you to **remove** agents from the process using the `remove` function of blocks, which I think exists for all blocks in all libraries that an agent could spend time in (and thus it make sense to remove them from). But then, if you want to delete them, you have to handle that part explicitly yourself:

- If the pedestrians had been added to the (hidden) default population via a `PedSource` block, then here you would *have* to use `deleteSelf`.
- If the pedestrians had been added to the process via a `PedEnter`, or the `PedSource` had been set to add them to a custom population (which is a common thing to do so your ped agents exist in a single named population), you'd delete them via the standard `remove_<popname>` function created by AnyLogic when you define a population --- see the *AnyLogic Help > Agent Based Modeling > Adding and removing agents from population dynamically* help page.

Note that using a sink block also visually represent the 'remove and delete' possibility (and logic) in the process flow which is better IMO.

**NB**: Having said this, only the Pedestrian library has this special universal cancel-from-blocks-into-a-special-visual-flow mechanism so, when using process flows from other libraries (e.g., the standard Process Modeling Library), it may be more convenient to use `remove` if the need to remove them (and delete them or not) is determined by logic outside the process flow (such as in agent statecharts).

Comment: Thank you very much for your  informative and comprehensive answer @Stuart. It is very valuable as it conceptualize the method.